# FastAPI, nginx, Docker Explicitly Add Each Endpoint

Tags: python, nginx, docker-compose, fastapi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a simple `FastAPI` that returns a string based on a query parameter at the endpoint `/day`. Trying to deploy using `Docker` and `nginx` as a reverse proxy. In order to get `http://localhost:3000/api/day?day_num=5` to work, I needed to explicitly add `location /api/day` to my `nginx-setup.conf`. I would receive an error if I only had `location /api/` and tried to visit `http:localhost:3000/api/day`.

How can I avoid having to explicitly add each endpoint? Is there a way to make `/api/day`, `/api/docs` and any other valid endpoints for `localhost:8000` (port Docker exposes for the backend service) work when I visit `http:localhost:3000/api/{valid endpoints}`?

`main.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/day", tags=["Dates"])
async def get_day_of_week(day_num: int = 0):
    """
    Get the current day of week
    """
    days = ['Sun', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'S']
    return days[day_num]
```

I am trying to use `nginx` as a reverse proxy.

`nginx-setup.conf`

```
upstream api {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /api/day {
        proxy_pass http://api/day;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --root-path /api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
     - 3000:8080
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx-setup.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you don't have the extra location block present?

Comment: Status Code 404 when I look at Network tab in Chrome.

Comment: Then you're probably looking for `proxy_pass http://api/;` instead, since the complete original URL will be kept if you don't have the trailing slash in your `proxy_pass` instruction.

Comment: I do not see an nginx 404 error in Chrome when I visit `http://localhost:3000/api/day?day_num=2`. Only see the `FastAPI` "detail": "Not Found". See 404 if I go to the network tab. If I check the docker container I see:`demo-app-backend-1 - "GET /api/day?day_num=2 HTTP/1.0" 404 Not Found
demo-app-nginx-1   "GET /api/day?day_num=2 HTTP/1.1" 404 22

Comment: Yes, the trailing slash `/` should fix that - without it your backend will see `/api/day` as the address (which the log shows) and not `/day` as you assume. Add the trailing slash to your `proxy_pass` and it should remove the matching `location` part.

Comment: Yes confirming adding the the trailing slash `/` to `proxy_pass` fixes the errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have a trailing slash in the `proxy_pass` entry, the path will be included verbatim. So:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://api;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Will result in the backend seeing `/api/day` as the request path. Since your application only expects `/day`, you have to modify your `proxy_pass` directive to include a trailing slash - this tells nginx to strip the matching part from the `location /api/` entry (and you should have a trailing slash here as well).

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://api/;  # <- trailing slash
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i debugged for a day to solve this, could not do due to this /

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the trailing slash in your location configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location /api/ {
-----------------^ remove this one
        proxy_pass http://api;
```

Nginx replaces the location with a non-trailing-slash uri. So, http://yourserver/api/something will become http://apisometing (note the concatenation).

Comment: This doesn't fix it. When I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/day` I get status code 404 when I look in the Network tab in Chrome.